# Using ffmpeg apply audio filter dynaudnorm to multiple audiostreams in avi

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, avi, audio-conversion

I have a avi file `video-double-audio.avi` with 1 video stream and multiple audio streams

```
# ffprobe video-double-audio.avi
...
[avi @ 0x559498d59080] non-interleaved AVI
Input #0, avi, from 'video-double-audio.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:19.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11151 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 10149 kb/s, 100 fps, 50 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s
```

And I want to apply the `dynaudnorm` audio filter, so I execute the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i video-double-audio.avi -af 'dynaudnorm=n=0:c=1' -c:v copy video-out.avi
```

However, now there is only a single audio stream left in `video-out.avi`

```
# ffprobe video-out.avi
[avi @ 0x556576b6d080] non-interleaved AVI
Input #0, avi, from 'video-out.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:20.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10278 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 10134 kb/s, 100 fps, 50 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
```

But now there is only a single audio stream left, the others seem to be removed..

Why does this happen?

And how can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of `-map`, ffmpeg will pick only one stream of each type. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Stream-selection

So, add mapping.

`ffmpeg -i video-double-audio.avi -map 0 -af 'dynaudnorm=n=0:c=1' -c:v copy video-out.avi`

Comment: Ah thanks, im in the road now but I'll try it as soon as I can!